# Java How to read text file and input it into different ArrayLists

Tags: java, file, arraylist, text

I'm a little confused on how to read text files of integers and put them into different ArrayLists as ints. They are separated by spaces and fill 3 lines.

For example the text file will have:
1 2 3 4 
5 4 3 2 
3 7 8 5

And I want to put each line into an ArrayList, so 
list[0] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list[1] = [5, 4, 3, 2]
list[2] = [3, 7, 8, 5]

My current code can only get one line and I'm not sure how to approach it, just need some guidance. Thank you.

My code:

```
  ArrayList<Integer> s1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  ArrayList<Integer> s2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  ArrayList<Integer> s3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  String line = null;

  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    s1.add(new Integer(line));
    s2.add(new Integer(line));
    s3.add(new Integer(line));
  }
```

The result should be an List containing every line into an List of Integers

Comment: Where is your current code ? Please provide it

Comment: should this [1, 2, 3, 4] be a string? or what format do you want?

Comment: As ints. I provided code, I'm aware that s2 and s3 are getting the same data but I was testing things out.

Comment: so 1 array list for each line?

Comment: Each line is inserted in the ArrayList, what should be the container of one line, int[], String, ArrayList<Integer>, ... ?

Comment: Yes, 1 ArrayList for each line.

Comment: So you want an ArrayList containing the ArrayList of Integers ? You will need to split the line to find the integers to insert in the List. There is already answers for this on SO.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to be able to read one line an insert the result into a List

```
String line = "1 2 3 4";
String[] array = line.split(" "); //Split the String one each Space and have the result into an Array
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(String value : array){ //Read the array, String by String
    list.add(Integer.valueOf(value)); //Parse and insert into the list
}
```

Here, `list` will contain one line.
Then you need to insert this result into the main list.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    // split the line
    fileList.add(list);
}
```

The full code would look like :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] array = line.split(" ");
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String value : array){
        list.add(Integer.valueOf(value));
    }

    fileList.add(list);
}
```

This is a code not test written here but this should be correct.

I have write this answer step by step to explain how to take one problem at the time ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> s1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
            ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (String str : numbers) {

                ints.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
            }
            s1.add(ints);
        }
```

this will give you an arraylist full of arraylists of type integer, filled with the values of each line

Comment: I prefer to use `Integer.valueOf(String)` in this situation to receive a Integer directly, if not, this will required to be wrapped. Not sure if this change anything on Runtime but functions exists ;)

Comment: as i understand the documentation this doesn't make any difference. `Integer.valueOf(s)`is `new Integer(Integer.parseInt(s))`

Answer (score -1):

***This code reads in each word and puts it into the ArrayList:***

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("filepath"));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
//As we need to add multiple tokens seperately
list.addAll((s.next()).split(" "));
}
s.close();
```

also we might require to Parse it while converting String to Integer as suggested in question.

Comment: This code is similar to how I would read one line. How would I separate the lines to put it into different ArrayLists?

Comment: @James if you read one line already try to split it like that:
String[] parts = string.split(" ");